# Is it possible to initialize the argument of a method with a self.variable value from __init__ in python?

Tags: python, oop, methods

I have a class with an `__init__` method where I define some variables, as well as a method `AddSignalSpectrum`:

```
class SpectrumGraph:
    
    # Properties
    def __init__(self):
        self.PlotHeight= 300 
        self.PlotWidth = 800 
        self.xRangeMin = -10 
        self.xRangeMax = 10
        self.yRangeMin = -0.1*(self.xRangeMax - self.xRangeMin)
        self.yRangeMax = 0.9*(self.xRangeMax -self.xRangeMin)

    def AddSignalSpectrum( 
        self,
        name,
        Type,
        CenterPosition,
        Bandwidth=2,
        Height = self.yRangeMax*0.8, 
        Color = "#0000FF", 
        LineWidth = 2,
        AbscissaSymbol = '$\omega_0$',
        ShowLegend = False):
     # Rest of the method
```

What I want is to provide the default value of self.yRangeMax*0.8 to the method but when I do that I get an error saying that 'self' is not defined. I can use attributes of `self` inside the method just fine, but it does not seem to work within the arguments of the method definition. I assume this is some sort of name space problem but can't find a workaround. It could be I'm just not sure what exactly to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not initialization, it is setting *defaults* for function parameters. The problem isn't to do with namespaces, it's to do with *binding*.

These values are determined *once, ahead of time* and are stored as part of the function (or method) object. It is not possible to use attributes of the `self` parameter here because there *isn't one* at the time that this happens. It is the same thing with ordinary functions:

```
def example(a, b=a+3): # doesn't work; `a` is not defined ahead of time
    print(f'a={a} and b={b}')
```

The normal workaround for this is to use `None` as the default value, and then explicitly check for this in the logic and replace `None` with the desired calculation:

```
def example(a, b=None): # works
    if b is None:
        b = a + 3
    print(f'a={a} and b={b}')

# and now we can call:
example(1) # 'a=1 and b=4'
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is to set a sentinel value (idiomatically `None`) and then define behavior inside the method, e.g.:

```py
def Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, friend):
        self.name = name
        self.friend = friend

    def say_hello(self, other=None):
        if other is None:
            other = self.friend

        print(f"Hello {other}, I'm {self.name}! How are you? Bark!")
```